# In NetBeans, how do I convert a "Java Application" Project to a "Web Application" Project?

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans

In NetBeans, how do I convert a "Java Application" Project to a "Web Application" Project?

Comment: Is it a Maven build or an Ant build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know there is no direct convert option.

In the past what I've done is either added the "Java Applicaton" as a dependency in a new web application or created a new web application and moved the code over.

Answer (score 6):

If it is Maven project, try adding this line to your POM file:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

I've just added it and it changed from java app (red coffee icon) to web app (blue globe icon; if that is what you mean) automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem coming up; Try this utility:

[erichauser.net/2009/10/26/ant2maven-easy-migration-from-ant-to-maven-with-nexus](http://erichauser.net/2009/10/26/ant2maven-easy-migration-from-ant-to-maven-with-nexus/)

Answer (score 0):

Try delete the NetBeans Project configuration files and create a Web Application with existing sources.